# prove that every polynomial in $\mathbb{R}[x]$ is continuous everywhere (a very simple proof)

Tags: calculus, continuity

> Prove that every polynomial in $\mathbb{R}[x]$ is continuous everywhere

**Note: this proof should only use the epsilon-delta definition of a limit.** Nonetheless, it's probably really easy, even if I mess up on a few steps.

Here's my attempt. Feel free to point out anything wrong/inefficient.

A polynomial $p(x)$ in $\mathbb{R}[x]$ is of the form $a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\dots+a_0.$

Lemma: If $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are continuous at $a,$ then $f(x)+g(x)$ is continuous at $a.$

Proof of lemma: Since $f(x)$ is continuous at $a,$ $\forall \epsilon >0,\exists \delta >0 \; (0<|x-a|<\delta \Rightarrow |f(x)-f(a)|<\dfrac{\epsilon}{2}.$ Similarly, since $g(x)$ is continuous at $a,$ $\forall \epsilon >0,\exists \delta >0 \; (0<|x-a|<\delta \Rightarrow |g(x)-g(a)|<\dfrac{\epsilon}{2}.$ 
Thus we have that $|f(x)-g(x)-(f(a)-g(a))|\le |f(a)-f(a)|+|g(x)-g(a)|<\dfrac{\epsilon}{2}+\dfrac{\epsilon}{2}=\epsilon.$ ${\square}$

Thus, from the lemma, by induction, if $a_ix^i$ is continuous at a point $a$ for some $i\in [0,n],$ then $p(x)$ is continuous. So it suffices to show that $a_ix^i, 0\le i \le n$ is continuous at a point $a.$ We need to estimate $|a_ix^i-a_ia^i|=|a_i||(x^i-a^i)|$ when $0<|x-a|<\delta.$ We know that $|x^i-a^i| =|x-a||x^{i-1}+ax^{i-2}+\dots+a^{i-1}|.$ Now, $|x^{i-1}+ax^{i-2}+\dots+a^{i-1}|$ is finite, so let $C$ denote its value. Choose $\delta = \dfrac{\epsilon}{Ca_i}$ and we have that $|a_ix^i-a_ia^i| <|a_i|\left(\dfrac{\epsilon}{Ca_i}C\right)=\epsilon,$ and so we are done.

Comment: If you are allowed to prove lemmas then you should also prove the product rule, from which the whole result follows

Comment: I know how to prove the product rule, but how does the whole result follow from the product rule? because differentiability implies continuity, right? that's also easy to prove

Comment: No, product rule for continuity. The product of continuous functions is continuous. And in the lemma for sum rule you can also add that $ af + bg$ is continuous for any constants a,b. But actually your proof looks ok. The product rule is the 'standard' proof

Comment: When you said the x + blah is finite, you should use the assumption |x-a|<delta to prove this

Comment: If $|x-a|<\delta,$ then $a-\delta<x<a+\delta.$ Thus, since $a$ is finite, $x$ is finite, and so any nonlinear combination of $x$ is finite. In particular, $x^{i-1}+ax^{i-2}+\dots+a^{i-1}$ is finite. Does that sound okay to you?

Comment: Well, what's a nonlinear combination... is $\frac1{x-a}$ a nonlinear combination? Its better to stick to the maths :) Triangle inequality should be useful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proof in its broad strokes is good, though there is the one thing which I pointed out in the comments, regarding:

> Now, $|x^{i-1}+ax^{i-2}+\dots+a^{i-1}|$ is finite, so let $C$  denote its value.

This $C$ is used to define $\epsilon$, and $\epsilon$ should be written not in terms of $x$, but in terms of only $\delta$ and $a$.

A more minor point, the pattern in the $+\dots+$ is not the clearest to see because the first and last terms both have the power $i+1$. Its easier (IMO) to read $\sum_{j=0}^{i-1} a^j x^{i-1-j}$.

Anyway, for the first point, you can note that $|x| \le |a| + \delta$. I suggest that you convince yourself that for $i>1$,

$$ \left| \sum_{j=0}^{i-1} a^j x^{i-1-j}\right| \le \sum_{j=0}^{i-1} |a|^j \big||a|+\delta\big|^{i-1-j}.$$
If you wanted something cleaner on the right, you could try 
$$ \left| \sum_{j=0}^{i-1} a^j x^{i-1-j}\right| \le i(|a|+\delta)^{i-1}.$$

Its not clear to me what you would mean by a "nonlinear combination of $x$ is finite"; for instance, $\frac1{x-a}$ is not bounded. So its better to just write the inequality you actually mean.

PS the "standard" proof (at least, whereever I looked) uses the following lemmas; if $f,g$ are continuous at $a$, and $c$ is a constant, then:

1. $f+g$ is continuous at $a$
2. $fg$ is continuous at $a$
3. $cf$ is continuous at $a$
4. $x$ is continuous everywhere
5. constant functions are continuous everywhere

Now any polynomial is built by applying the first 3 operations on $ x$ and $1$, so the result follows.

Comment: +1 and a little nitpick. You also need the fact that constant functions are continuous to deal with the constant term in polynomial.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh ..thats very true! thanks :)